# Is there a relational database with GUI for Mac similar to Microsoft Access or the like?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, switching, mysql, database

I need a desktop database that will have a need for extensive 1-many, many-1, and many to many relationships.

I've built this kind of app with Microsoft Access, which I don't love, but does combine the database and a useful GUI.

Relational Database apps for Mac seem pretty thin. Filemaker's "relational" features are not much like anything I've used before.

Panorama is interesting, but also not really relational, no SQL, etc.

Is there a database system for Mac that functions similar to Microsoft Access?

UPDATE: While I am quite happy to use most of the tools suggested so far, I am looking for something which has an interface that non-technical types can use. It doesn't have to be as sophisticated as Access (which isn't all that sophisticated, I guess), but something more than a management tool. I should have been clearer; I thought the parallel to Access would speak for itself.

As far as I can tell, Filemaker is not an SQL database, though I guess it can speak to SQL databases in some way, so maybe I could kludge something together there. I'll try out the MySQL and SQLite tools as well, though they appear to be management tools...