# MySQL GUI Tools Recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql

What is your recommendation for MySQL GUI Tools?
I'm looking for software has interface similar to MySQL Workbench.

1. Have tab query editor without reconnect to database
2. Can easily add new row
3. Can easily see table structure

Software that i have tried:
**MySQL Workbench:**
I don't mind it slower at startup but it contains bugs for `alter` query

**Sequel Pro**
I fast at startup, but not easy to see table structure.
New tab query editor require to reconnect.

Comment: What's wrong with Sequel Pro's Structure view?

Comment: @WarrenPena  when we still in type in `query editor` we need to click the structure button which it is will close the `query editor` and change it into `structure view`.  I need both display at once.

Comment: Ah. You could always open the Structure view in a separate window.  Certainly not as elegant as a true split view, but it gets the job done.  I don't have any other clients to recommend that do that, though.

Comment: no separate window please. It will not elegant as you told @_@

Comment: Check my post about Valentina Studio here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-relational-database-with-gui-for-mac-similar-to-microsoft-access-or-t

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com). But there are 'native' binaries for Mac OS-x. Read [FAQ](http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/31/181/en/can-i-use-sqlyog-on-a-mac.html).