# need a database software for Mac 10

Tags: mac, software

Is there q simple data base out there that is similar to the database the was included in the old Apple Works software

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a relational database with GUI for Mac similar to Microsoft Access or the like?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/is-there-a-relational-database-with-gui-for-mac-similar-to-microsoft-access-or-t)

Answer (score 1):

Apple recently discontinued Bento. It was an easy to use simplified version of their pro product Filemaker pro.

there are still copies of it around the internet for sale (Amazon, Ebay, etc.) That would be a reasonable choice.

But if you will be needing a current and currently supported product you may have to look elsewhere.

You could try OpenOffice, which has a DB module and is free. Also if you have MS Access you could use a VM (VirtualBox, Parallels, VMWare) with Windows or Codeweavers Crossover Office to just run Access without Windows.

A quick search of the App Store might give you something that works for you as well.